# Чем ad hoc полиморфизм отличается от обычного полиморфизма?

Tags: c#

Как я понимаю в C# полиморфизм заключается в использовании виртуальных членов и в приведении типов, но наткнулся еще на упоминание ad hoc полиморфизма, и никак не могу понять чем же он отличается от использования виртуальных членов?

Comment: http://rsdn.org/forum/philosophy/2853873.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, ad hoc-полиморфизм — это полиморфизм, основанный на различении *типов*. Для различных типов аргументов используется разный код функции.

Один классический пример — это *перегрузка* (overloading) метода:

```
class C
{
    public void f(int x) { Console.WriteLine("C.f(int)"); }
    public void f(string x) { Console.WriteLine("C.f(string)"); }
}
```

Здесь имя `f` привязано к двум различным методам, и компилятор выбирает тот или иной метод в зависимости от типа аргумента. Это пример *статического* ad hoc-полиморфизма: типы должны быть известны на этапе компиляции, и компилятор точно знает, который из методов будет выполнен.

Другой пример ad hoc-полиморфизма — это *переопределение* (overriding) виртуального метода:

```
class B
{
    public virtual void f(int x) { Console.WriteLine("B.f(int)"); }
}

class D : B
{
    public override void f(int x) { Console.WriteLine("D.f(int)"); }
}
```

Здесь также происходит различение по типам, но на этот раз — по типу неявного нулевого аргумента `this`. Выбор переопределённого метода откладывается на момент выполнения; на момент компиляции компилятор точно не знает, какой из группы переопределённых методов будет выполнен. Это пример *динамического* ad hoc-полиморфизма.

---

Кроме того, есть ещё понятие *параметрического* полиморфизма: это ситуация, когда один и тот же метод работает с аргументами различных типов одинаково, не зависимо от их точного типа. Тривиальный пример для языков с наследованием (например, C#) — функция, работающая с объектом некоторого класса `C`, часто может без изменений работать с объектом порождённого от `C` класса (этот вид полиморфизма часто называют *полиморфизм включения*). Менее тривиальный пример — generic-методы, которые могут, в зависимости от generic-параметра, работать с разными типами объектов. Пример:

```
class Enumerable
{
    public T First(this IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> en = seq.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!en.MoveNext())
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return en.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но как я понял это использование `dynamic`, хотя возможно я и не правильно разобрался, идея в том что если у некоторых классов есть одноименный метод (соответственно сигнатура метода тоже одинакова), но эти методы не имеют общего родителя или интерфейса, то с помощью dynamic можно подменять экземпляры во время выполнения и вызывать метод.

Comment: @e1s: Метод с `dynamic` внутри — ещё один валидный пример _параметрического_ полиморфизма. (Но не ad hoc, по идее.) Хотя, вызов правильного метода при использовании `f((dynamic)o)` — это снова ad hoc-полиморфизм.

Comment: `часто может без изменений работать с объектом порождённого от C класса` — уточню: если этот объект соблюдает *принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков*.

Answer (score 1):

Постараюсь обяснить по основанию книги ГОФ

**Ad-Hock Полиморфизм это**

- Классический (Принудительный) полиморфизм т. е. Возможность динамической подмены типов 
  (объектов) во время выполнения программы, но без второй формы Инкапсуляции т. е. без сокрытия реализации (Когда вы в классическом полиморфизме делаете upcast то происходит сокрытие свойств и методов из производного типа).

или

- Возможность обращаться с объектами у которых одинаковый интерфейс взаимодействия одинаковым образом

**Пример.**

```
class A{public void Method(){Console.WriteLine("A");}}

class B{public void Method(){Console.WriteLine("B");}}

class C{public void Method(){Console.WriteLine("C");}}
```

У этих классов нету базового класса но у них одинаковый интерфейс взаимодействия.

Ad hoc полиморфизм или (Полиморфизм для конкретного случая) позволяет обращаться схожим образом к объектам, не связанным классическим наследованием.

**Пример.**

```
// данный интерфейс создан для создания своего рода базового типа для классов А, B, и C у которых нету таковой.

interface IInterface
    {
        void Method();
    }
 //в данном случае мы создаем новые классы обертки с схожими интерфейсами и с базовым типом
    class MyA : A, IInterface { }
    class MyB : B, IInterface { }
    class MyC : C, IInterface { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
//тем самым мы работаем с классами как будто у них был базовый тип но  без сокрытия реализации
                IInterface instance = new MyA();
                instance.Method();
                instance = new MyB();
                instance.Method();
                instance = new MyC();
                instance.Method();
         }
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

Есть 3 основных вида полиморфизма (покажу на примере php, c# не знаю):

1. **Ad hoc** полиморфизм — несколько объявлений функции с одинаковым именем но с отличающимися параметрами, пример:

При вызове функции выберется та которой соответствует тип аргумента.

```
function test (string $a, string $b) {
    return $a . $b;
}
function test (int $a, int $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

// если бы в пхп поддерживалось, то вывело бы
test('a', 'b') // 'ab'
test(1, 4) // 5
```

2. **Параметрический** полиморфизм — когда будет выполнятся одна и та же функция вне зависимости от типов аргументов.

В php он поддерживается.

```
function test (string $a, string $b) {
    return $a . $b;
}
function test (int $a, int $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

// если бы в пхп поддерживалось, то вывело бы
test('a', 'b') // 'ab'
test(1, 4) // 5
```

Параметрический полиморфизм является истинной формой полиморфизма, делая язык более выразительным и существенно повышая коэффициент повторного использования кода. 
Традиционно ему противопоставляется Ad hoc полиморфизм (мнимая форма).

3. **Subtype** полиморфизм — насколько понял это самое популярное понятие полиморфизма.

Это возможность объектов с одинаковой спецификацией иметь различную реализацию.

Например, есть интерфейс LoggerInterface, это как спецификация. Если есть классы которые имплементируют этот интерфейс, например, класс FileLogger и DBLogger, то это называется полиморфизмом.

```php
interface LoggerInterface {
  public function log($logs);
}

class FileLogger implements LoggerInterface {
  public function log($logs) 
  {
    // записывает логи в файл
  }
}

class DBLogger implements LoggerInterface {
  public function log($logs) 
  {
    // записывает логи в БД
  }
}
```

Вместо интерфейса может быть наследование через абстрактный (виртуальный) класс или даже обычный класс.

То есть когда есть методы в разных классах которые делают то же самое, 
им можно дать одинаковое имя и сделать чтобы эти классы реализовывали единый интерфейс 
или наследовали единый абстрактный класс с этим абстрактным методом.