# Является ли перегрузка методов полиморфизмом?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, терминология

В нескольких статьях я прочитал вот такое:

> Перегрузка методов поддерживает свойство полиморфизма, поскольку именно таким способом в C# реализуется главный принцип полиморфизма: один интерфейс — множество методов.

Пообщавшись с коллегами по этому поводу, большинство высказалось что перегрузка методов(overload) не имеет ничего общего с полиморфизмом. Так ли это?

Comment: *override* или *overload* ?

Comment: @4per, overload

Comment: @4per `override` это `переопределение`. Хотя в русских переводах порой случается бардак.

Comment: @alexolut да, я тоже чаще встречаю перевод `переопределение`, но `перегрузка` тоже попадалось. Другое дело, что слова звучат похоже, особенно на английском и перепутать ненароком можно.

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464752/10105

Answer (score 11):

#### И да, и нет. Смотря что они имеют в виду под полиморфизмом.

---

В *общем* случае полиморфизм это **возможность обращаться одинаковым образом с сущностями разных типов**. Или, чуть более научно, существование общего интерфейса (в отрыве от C#) у сущностей различных типов. Это очень общее понятие, которое можно очень много на что натянуть. Что при этом произойдёт и какие абстракции языка при этом будут задействованы, не столь важно.

**К этому полиморфизму перегрузка методов относится самым прямым образом:** это **ad-hoc** полиморфизм для функции: в неё можно передавать различные типы (в границах реализованных перегрузок) и при этом будет выполнен **разный** код. (А методы объектов классов можно рассматривать, как функции с дополнительным неявным аргументом: объектом, у которого метод вызывается [`this` в шарпе].)

Может возникнуть закономерный вопрос: *не являются ли тогда различные перегрузки разными функциями, не ломается ли при этом соответствие определению полиморфизма?* Ответ: полиморфизм существует на уровне **языка**, и если в языке перегрузки с одинаковыми названиями, но разными типами, считаются одной и той же функцией, то определение соблюдено и всё ок.

Уровнями ниже, конечно, разный код размещается в разных местах и реализация как-то должна направлять в разные места, технически обращаясь с переданными значениями по-разному. Но вы с этими уровнями напрямую уже не работаете, полиморфизм там если и есть (что вряд ли) то не совсем (или совсем не?) тот, которым вы пользуетесь.

---

В ООП же под полиморфизмом обычно понимают гораздо более узкое понятие: возможность вызывать один и тот же метод у любого объекта заданного класса/интерфейса или любого его подкласса/реализации.

**К этому полиморфизму перегрузка действительно не имеет отношения.**

Answer (score 9):

Перегрузка функций это [ad hoc полиморфизм](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism).

(*Ad hoc, лат, ситуационно, на данный случай)

---

Традиционно, в ООП сообществе "полиморфизмом" принято называть только разновидность полиморфизма связанную с подтипами. При этом в ФП сообществе "полиморфизмом" называют параметрический полиморфизм. Википедия приводит [три вида полиморфизма в CS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) - ad hoc, параметрический и подтипы. Впрочем другие источники могут предлагать иное деление.

Термины "статический" и "динамический" полиморфизм применимы только к конкретной реализации конкретного языка, в частности в языке с динамической типизацией перегрузка функций может быть реализована во время работы программы.

Comment: Что такое *ФП сообщество* и как это относится к вопросу автора? Конкретный язык, затронутый в вопросе - `C#`.

Comment: эм...может быть я не так вопрос задал. Про существование парадигм я, в принципе, подозревал, но суть не в этом. Я конкретно спросил про сообщество, которое мне не известно. А про конкретный язык написал, потому что Вы в ответе написали *применимы только к конкретной реализации конкретного языка*, а автор вопроса указал конкретный язык - `C#`.

Comment: просто из всех ответов - три ответа про *статический* и *динамический* полиморфизм. Ничего конкретного не приведено, лишь понятия и абстракции. Мне бы, как и автору вопроса, хотелось бы увидеть что-то более конкретное. Вот к чему я...

Comment: @DenisBubnov, а мне кажется что правильный. Ведь понятие полиморфизм существует как во многих языках, так и в программировании в частности. Во всех языках и парадигмах разный полиморфизм и поэтому когда будут говорить два программиста одного языка, но разных парадигм то может возникнуть не понимание. А чего уж говорить о споре программистов из разных языков. Поэтому знание всего сказанного лишь пойдут на пользу и поможет глубже разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: @OlmerDale, пойдет на пользу - да. Но ответа на вопрос я не вижу.

Comment: @DenisBubnov это потому, что Вы из тех, кто на вопрос "как лучше повесится" ответите что веревку нужно мылом натирать, а я и автор ответа, да и автор вопроса, я надеюсь, из те кто попытается отговорить от этой затеи.

Comment: @OlmerDale, вот этот ответ про веревку меня улыбнул :) да, Вы правы, относительно этого, но лишь частично. Но вот, что же означает *ФП*, я так и не узнал. Функциональное программирование? Да нет, его так никогда не называли...

Comment: @DenisBubnov, ФП, да, функциональное программирование, а как его по другому называли и когда я не знаю. просто сейчас время когда даже только начинающие должны знать о различных парадигмах и подходах. Мне кажется что если года на три забыть о форумах, уйти в работу, то потом придется учится у детей, которые две недели назад начали только видосы смотреть на youtube. Но это же хорошо!

Answer (score 6):

Полиморфизм бывает разным. В частности, **статическим** и **динамическим**.

**Динамический полиморфизм**  - это когда используется ссылка на объект базового класса и виртуальные функции.

**Статический полиморфизм**  - это когда определяется перегрузка нескольких функций на основании типов списка аргументов.

Так что здесь всё дело в терминологии. Возможно Ваши коллеги под полиморфизмом имеют в виду исключительно *динамический*.

Comment: Если не в кругу снобов и smartass'ов, то полиморфизм всегда является динамическим, ежели не указано обратное явно. По крайней мере так показывает мой опыт.

Comment: @ixSci вот это мы и пытаемся выяснить.

Comment: @Abyx это применимо к c#?

Comment: @Abyx, как Вы себе представляете перегрузку в рантайме?

Comment: @Abyx, пример можете привести?

Comment: @Abyx я старался не выходить за рамки c#, т.к. в вопросе он не только меткой, но и в тексте встречается.

Comment: @Abyx, именно. Пример на C#.

Comment: @alexolut, мне тоже интересно на этот пример посмотреть.

Answer (score 6):

Понятие полиморфизма не имеет четкого определения, но для объктно-ориентированного подхода обычно принимают что существует два типа полиморфизма:

1. Динамический (использование виртуальных методов и их переопределение в классах потомках) - в этом случае версия вызываемого кода определяется CLR на этапе выполнения, проходя по цепи переопределений в классах потомков.
2. Статический (использование обобщений (generics)) - в этом случае используется одна и таже версия кода для объектов различных типов.

Перегрузка методов исходя из вышеприведенной терминологии не является полиморфизмом, т.к. конкретный код и тип объекта известен на этапе КОМПИЛЯЦИИ. Другими словами, в данном случае мы просто имеем РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ методы с одинаковым именем, различающиеся типами или количеством передаваемых параметров.

С тем же результатом мы могли бы добавить к имени метода типы параметров, и с точки зрения архитектуры приложения ничего не изментиться, а полимрфизм - это, в первую очередь, инструмент архитектурного подхода к решению задач.

Comment: @Abyx, это не мешает им быть «статическими», т.к. всё, что нужно проверяется на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @Abyx, не аргумент. Виртуальный вызов может быть чем угодно и внутри него может происходить всё, что угодно. Мы заранее вообще ничего не можем сказать о том, что произойдёт: происходит динамическое связывание. С generics всё иначе: жёсткие ограничения, и никакого динамического связывания.

Answer (score 3):

> В C# допускается совместное использование одного и того же имени двумя
>   или более методами одного и того же класса, при условии, что их
>   параметры объявляются по-разному. В этом случае говорят, что методы
>   перегружаются, а сам процесс называется перегрузкой методов.

Рассмотри вот такой простой метод:

```
public void OverloadMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Пустой");
}
```

И напишем методы, перегружающие его:

```
public void OverloadMethod(string one)
{
    Console.WriteLine(one);
}

public void OverloadMethod(string one, string two)
{
    Console.WriteLine(one + "+" + two);
}
```

Мы перегрузили метод `OverloadMethod` два раза.

Что можем увидеть во время вызова метода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Перегрузка методов поддерживает свойство полиморфизма, поскольку
>   именно таким способом в C# реализуется главный принцип полиморфизма:
>   один интерфейс — множество методов.

В С# каждому методу может быть присвоено одно и то же имя. Компилятор C# сам определяет, какой именно вариант метода `OverloadMethod` следует вызывать, исходя из типа передаваемого аргумента, во время вызова метода.

> В C# определено понятие сигнатуры, обозначающее имя метода и список
>   его параметров; Применительно к перегрузке это понятие означает, что в
>   одном классе не должно существовать двух методов с одной и той же
>   сигнатурой. Следует подчеркнуть, что в сигнатуру не входит тип
>   возвращаемого значения, поскольку он не учитывается, когда компилятор
>   C# принимает решение о перегрузке метода. В сигнатуру не входит также
>   модификатор params.

Если бы C# не поддерживал перегрузки, то пришлось бы присваивать каждому методу свое имя, что не очень удобно. В данном случае метод `OverloadMethod` реализует несколько перегрузок.

> Полиморфизм - это принцип объектно-ориентированного программирования
>   после инкапсуляции и наследования. Это свойство, которое позволяет
>   одно и то же имя использовать для решения двух или более схожих, но
>   технически разных задач. Целью полиморфизма, применительно к
>   объектно-ориентированному программированию, является использование
>   одного имени для задания общих для класса действий.

Поняте полиморфизма зачастую трактуется по разному, можно увидеть массу понятий, но все сводится к одному. В результате, ответом на вопрос: *Является ли перегрузка методов полиморфизмом?* - я отвечаю ***ДА***.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблема в том что все понимают что такое перегруженный метод, но вот сложно доказать что к этому процессу причастен полиморфизм.

Comment: @Lightness, было бы неплохо увидеть определение полиморфизма

Comment: @Lightness, тогда видимо, что *все понимают что такое перегруженный метод* - не совсем уж правдиво.

Comment: @Abyx, скриншот из IDE был приведен лишь для визуального представления того, что получилось. В качестве аргумента дал частичное понятие полиморфизма с ориентацией на перегрузку методов.