# Как пользоваться полиморфизмом, но без классов с помощью языка С

Tags: c++, c, ооп, полиморфизм

Кто что слышал? Нужна инфа, заранее благодерен.

Comment: Вам для курсового/собеседования или что то свое решили запилить?

Comment: Для начала, мне кажется, надо определиться с самим понятием "полиморфизм"

Comment: Вопрос в билете к экзамену. Методички нету, гугл ответа не дал.

Comment: Полиморфизм и без классов??????????????

Comment: Например: [How can I simulate OO-style polymorphism in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/524033/2881286)

Comment: Ну, вы ж можете сэмулировать классы с таблицей виртуальных методов на C? Вот вам и полиморяизм. По сути, просто косвенный вызов функции.

Comment: Если, Вы понимаете, что такое полиморфизм, то сможете любую структуру с помощью указателей (адресов) на объекты и функции превратить в аналог с++ класса, однако дело это сложное и чреватое трудно вылавливаемыми ошибками

Comment: следует ознакомится с самим понятием "полиморфизм" https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) И, если имеется ввиду Ad hoc полиморфизм, то это просто перегрузка функций, но есть понятие полиморфизм подтипов и т.д.

Comment: Собственно, если это экзаменационный вопрос, то это вопрос с "подвохом" и требует базовых понятий теории типов. И, следовательно, если от вас это и имеют ввиду, следует привести примеры реализации различных видов полиморфизма на чистом С, а это не сказать, что тривиально :)

Comment: да ну что вы говорите?! Полиморфизм подтипов элементарно делается через структуры данных.

Comment: [**О несколько более вольной (нежели обычно) трактовке понятия полиморфизма.**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594956/181100) Следуя этому, явление полиморфизма можно углядеть и в макросах на базе препроцессора, которые могут работать со значениями разных типов.

Answer (score 4):

Ну вот, например :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _foo {

    union {
        char c;
        int i;
    } data;

    void (*print)(struct _foo *);

} foo;

static void print_char(foo *bar)
{
    printf( "data.char: %c\n", bar->data.c );
}

static void print_int(foo *bar)
{
    printf( "data.int : %d\n", bar->data.i );
}

int main(void)
{
    foo int_foo  = { .data.i = 1,   .print = print_int  };
    foo char_foo = { .data.c = 'a', .print = print_char };
    foo *foo_ptr;

    foo_ptr = &char_foo;
    foo_ptr->print(foo_ptr);

    foo_ptr = &int_foo;
    foo_ptr->print(foo_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Рискну дать свои записи из комментариев, как некий обобщенный ответ на вопрос.
Дело в том, что понятие *полиморфизм* - несколько более широкое понятие, нежели просто вызов виртуальных функциий в С++.

Следует ознакомиться с самим понятием "полиморфизм". Википедия, конечно не претендует на академичность, но все же [полезно почитать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

К примеру т.н. *Ad hoc полиморфизм* - это просто перегрузка функций. Полиморфизм подтипов - это совсем другое дело.

Т.е. насколько я могу понять, если это экзаменационный вопрос, то он требует хотя бы какого-то знания теории типов и хорошее владение языком С.

Мне кажется, что вам следует разобрать конкретные виды полиморфизма и попытаться реализовать каждый вид, используя относительно низкоуровневый язык. Это вполне возможно, но придется потрудиться.