# Каким видом полиморфизма является этот код?

Tags: php, ооп, полиморфизм

```
class A {
    public function method1() {
        return $this->method2();
    }

    protected function method2() {
        return 'A';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected function method2() {
        return 'B';
    }
}

$b = new B();
echo $b->method1();
```

Нашел такой код на одном сайте, там пишут, что это полиморфизм. Но где тут полиморфизм? Я вижу тут переопределение метода и все. Чтобы был полиморфизм подтипов (включения), здесь не хватает функции, которая будет в аргументах принимать подтипы базового класса А. Верно же?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Является ли перегрузка методов полиморфизмом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594867/%d0%af%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: грубо говоря полиморфизм - когда можно вызвать один и тот же метод у разных подтипов одного типа и получить разные результаты (если необходимо)..........по факту, это тут и происходит......

Comment: а то, о чём ты говоришь - скорее относится к SOLID и конкретно к L

Comment: Я открыл страницу вики про полиморфизм. Из всего что там есть, я нашел полиморфизм подтипов (включения) и там вот что написано:

"полиморфизм подтипов означает, что поведение параметрически полиморфной[⇨] функции ограничивается множеством типов, ограниченных в иерархию «супертип — подтип»[23][10][24]. Например, если имеются типы Number, Rational и Integer, ограниченные отношениями Number :> Rational и Number :> Integer, то функция, определённая на типе Number, также сможет принять на вход аргументы типов Integer или Rational, и её поведение будет идентичным. "

Comment: В моем примере выше нету функции которая принимает аргументы подтипов. Разве не так? Или как конкретно называется полиморфизм в моем примере? 

@АлексейШиманский

Comment: "В  моем примере выше нету функции которая принимает аргументы подтипов. "  ---- ты не так прочитал предложение из вики....... там написано что у подтипов определена какая-то функция..........а не то, что где-то есть функция, у которой есть аргумент в виде этого подтипа

Comment: Ad-hoc-полиморфизм это когда разные аргументы для одного и тогоже метода, вы видимо попутали @АлексейШиманский

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, чуть позже переосмыслю это и отпишусь

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном примере НЕТ полиморфизма.
Это пример наследования.

Полиморфизм, это когда с использованием переменной базового класса выполняются действия объекта, созданного на основе класса-потомка.

Если бы в примере была сделана типизация переменной `$b` по типу `A` и вызывался бы метод `method2` (для этого он должен быть публичным), тогда был бы полиморфизм.

Можно подумать, что в операторе

`$this->method2();`

в методе `method1()` класса `A` случается полиморфизм.

Но это не "чистый" пример полиморфизма. Так как метод используется изнутри самого базового класса. Это, скорее, пример абстракции.