# Разные виды полиморфизма

Tags: java, полиморфизм

В Java вот это:

3 основных вида полиморфизма?

1. ad hoc полиморфизм
2. Параметрический полиморфизм
3. Subtype полиморфизм

И каждый реализовывает  полиморфизм?

ИЛИ

Или это разные реализации полиморфизма?

Можете расписать подробно с примерами "полиморфизм"?

Полиморфизм это

> "один интерфейс — много реализаций"

ИЛИ

> "один интерфейс - много методов"

и чем это отличается?

Comment: сначала дай определение полиморфизма.

Comment: а какое практическое значение имеет этот вопрос?

Comment: @michael_best Никакого практического значения ни один вопрос на этом сайте не имеет.

Comment: @Grundy способность обьекта использовать методы производного класса, который не существует на момент создания базового.

Comment: @Grundy но я могу еще скинуть 1-2 определения где они отличаются от этого и вот фиг поймешь где золотая середина термина и является ли перегрузка полиморфизмом или нет

Comment: @ГеннадийВихренченко, ну вот чтобы понять, является ли что-то чем-то, сначала надо определить что такое это все эти `что`, тогда сразу станет понятно как они соотносятся между собой. Так как есть несколько вариантов определения, то, соответственно, есть несколько вариантов и ответа.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем ad hoc полиморфизм отличается от обычного полиморфизма?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464752/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-ad-hoc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Comment: @Grundy Вот я и пытаюсь определить, просто вижу одних и других, но одни за перезгрузку, другие за переопределение и не могу понять к какому лагерю отнестись)) Новичок поэтому и плохо ориентируюсь

Comment: @ГеннадийВихренченко, обрати внимание на вопрос дубликат, так рассматриваются два вида полиморфизма, и под один подходит переопределение методов, под второй - перегрузка

Comment: а почему полиморфизм не может быть и тем и другим одновременно? :-) Что-то после редактирования вопрос стал еще более непонятнее и шире чем был :)

Comment: Народ, не путайте пожалуйста. Полиморфизм - это о переопределении методов, а не о их перегрузке.

Comment: @Grundy потому что перегрузка - это отношение между методами в рамках одного класса, в то время, как полиморфизм относится к принципам взаимодействия дочерних/родительских классов

Comment: @AntonM, это ты где такое определение взял? :-) Вообще дай определение понятию "Полиморфизм" :-) чтобы было понятно что именно ты имеешь ввиду ;-)

Comment: @Grundy Полиморфизм (по крайней мере в моем понимании) - парадигма ООП, заключающаяся в способности обьекта использоваться в роли объекта производного класса.
Но, не зависимо от выбранного определения, все они сходятся как минимум в том, что это "Парадигма ООП".  Перегрузка методов к этому достаточно слабо относится

Comment: @AntonM, вот это стоило бы особо выделить: _(по крайней мере **в моем понимании**)_ :) То есть, ты хочешь сказать, что именно твое определение верное, иначе не стал бы в предыдущих комментария доказывать что остальные неправы? С чего ты взял, что полиморфизм заключается в _способности объекта использоваться в роли объекта производного класса_?

Comment: @Grundy это о моем понимании полиморфизма. После я описал, почему не может быть верен другой вариант. Речь идет о классах, в то время, как перегрузка относится к методам.

Comment: @AntonM, это только у тебя речь идет о _классах_ :-) Методы вообще говоря имеют прямое отношение к классам

Comment: @Grundy в данном случае, *метод* был назван так сугубо из-за его названия в рамках рассматриваемой темы. В целом же, если рассматривать эту тему более отстраненно, то будет правильнее определить данный объект как *функция*. Возможно это чуть больше прояснит картинку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86230/discussion-between-grundy-and-anton-m).